# Creating a Show instance on a type parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-cats

I am working through Scala with Cats and I am trying to create a `Show`  on a `Tree[A]` type (not a book exercise). Basically, I am trying to create an instance such that if I have any tree whose underlying values have a `Show` instance I can call `tree.show`. I am struggling with how to represent this.

So far, I have

```scala
sealed trait Tree[+A]
final case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
object Tree {

 implicit val show: Show[Tree[Show[_]]] = new Show[Tree[Show[_]]] {
     def show(t: Tree[Show[_]]): String = t match {
         case Branch(left, right) => s"*\n/\n${show(left)} ${show(right)}\n"
         case Leaf(value) => value.show
        }
    }
}
```

I get `missing argument list for method show in trait ContravariantShow
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing show _ or show(_) instead of`show`.`

When I rewrote as as `value.show(_)` I got `type mismatch; found   : _$3 => String required: String`

When I wrote just a string `"value"` to test, my `Tree[Int]` instance was not able to find a method `show` on type `Tree[Int]`.

Any ideas for how I can make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically, I am trying to create an instance such that if I have any tree whose underlying values have a Show instance.

This is the answer to your problem.
You can derive a **Show** for a `Tree[A]` as long as you know there is a **Show** for `A`.

```
object Tree {
  implicit def treeShow[A](implicit aShow: Show[A]): Show[Tree[A]] =
    new Show[Tree[A]] {
      override def show(t: Tree[A]): String = t match {
        case Branch(left, right) => s"*\n/\n${show(left)} ${show(right)}\n"
        case Leaf(value) => aShow.show(value)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cats provide string interpolation for `Show`, so you can also write shorter : `show"*\n/\n$left $right\n"`